# Sending lists with the Python lib requests

Tags: python, django, httprequest, python-requests

I have a python dict containing a list, for example:

```
d = {"x": 1, "y": ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

I want to send this dict with a POST from my python project using the `requests` lib like this:

```
requests.post(url, d, verify=False)
```

I manage to send and recieve the request fine but the problem is that when I'm printing the `request.POST` dict in my Django view it looks like this:

```
{"y": "c", "x": "1"}
```

The `y` key containing the list doesn't look as expected as the list has been reduced to just the last object of the list, in this case `"c"`. How do I send the list properly?

Comment: I meant to say list, changed all arrays in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`QueryDict.getlist()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to retrieve *all* values for a parameter that is repeated in the request:

```
y = request.POST.getlist('y')
```

This assumes that you instead posted `d = [('x', 1), ('y', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('y', 'c')]`; nested lists are not supported by `requests`.

Comment: Right, thanks, I do use the getlist method but are confusing myself by printing the whole request.POST. The `y` actually contains an array and not just the `"c"`.